# Why are the digits in my numbers printing separately rather than together?

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

This is an example of my code. It is not the whole code, it is just the part where I am having trouble. Does anyone understand why it prints like this rather than the full numbers, like 104.0 and 96.0? They are strings, but it will not allow me to convert it to a float because the period in some of the digits..

```
with open('file.csv','w') as file:
    with open('file2.csv', 'r') as file2:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file2)
        file.write(','.join(row))
        file.write('\n')
        for num,row in enumerate(reader):
            outrow = []
            for x in row['numbers']:
                print(x)
```

When I execute this, it prints out the values I am looking for but separately like this:

```
1
0
4
.
0
9
6
.
0
N
a
N
1
3
6
.
0
N
a
N
6
2
.
0
```

The 'NaN' are values I am changing, but the rest of the numbers I have to use. I cannot insert them into a list because they will end up separated right?

Comment: Did you mean: `print(row['numbers'])` rather than `for x in ...`?

Comment: @quamrana i was printing x to see if the values are the correct ones. i do not plan to keep the print statement, i was going to find the average of the numbers and assign it to the NaN ones using the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like:

```py
with open('file.csv','w') as file:
    with open('file2.csv', 'r') as file2:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file2)
        file.write(','.join(row))
        file.write('\n')
        for num,row in enumerate(reader):
            number = row['numbers']
            print(number)
```

`for x in row['numbers']` means, "Iterate over every individual character in the **numbers** cell/vallue".

Also, what are you doing here?

```py
        file.write(','.join(row))
        file.write('\n')
```

You don't have a `row` variable/object at that point (at least not visible in your example).  Are you trying to write the header?  Presumably it's working, so you defined `row` before, maybe like, `row = ['col1', 'numbers']`

If so, maybe take this general approach:

```py
import csv

# Do your reading and processing in one step
rows = []
with open('input.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)

    for row in reader:

        # do some work on row, like...
        number = row['numbers']
        if row['numbers'] == 'NaN':
             row['numbers'] = '-1'  # whatever you do with NaN

        rows.append(row)

# Do your writing in another step
my_field_names = rows[0].keys()

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    # Use the provided writer, in addition to reader
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=my_field_names)

    writer.writeheader()

    writer.writerows(rows)
```

At the very least, use the provide **writer** and **DictWriter** classes, they will make your life much easier.

I mocked up this sample CSV:

**input.csv**

```
id,numbers
id_1,100.4
id2,NaN
id3,23
```

and the program above produced this:

**output.csv**

```
id,numbers
id_1,100.4
id2,-1
id3,23
```